# Jenkins workflow job: Use parameter as branch specifier

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I want to migrate our old free style dev builds, in which we use the branch name as a build parameter, to workflow builds.
This works fine so far, the only thing we are really missing is the ability to use the parameter, e.g.  "branch_name", as the branch specifier for the *Workflow script from SCM* section.
On a free style build this works fine.
Any ideas how this could be achieved? We don't want a dev to change the configuration all the time before starting a build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [JENKINS-28447](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28447):

> When selecting the "Groovy CPS DSL from SCM" option for a worflow job,
>   the SCM plugins do not appear to resolve build parameters or
>   environment variables. I am using the git plugin and when I use it
>   from other jobs I can specify a build parameter, like "BuildBranch",
>   and use that when specifying what branch should be built

The workaround would be to use an inline bootstrap script that calls `load` after checkout, as described in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly describes my issue. I will try the "inline bootstrap script" approach.

Comment: For those looking at this it appears that this "issue" has essentially been marked "won't fix" (actually "resolved" but the comment suggests otherwise o_O ) [*Lightweight checkout is going through a completely unrelated code path, and currently SCMFileSystem implementations do not honor variables (or even have an API allowing them to honor variables IIRC). Would have to be a separate feature*](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28447?focusedCommentId=308351&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-308351)

Answer (score 46):

Try to disable "Lightweight checkout" checkbox.

[image: Lightweight checkout screenshot]

This behavior is noted when clicking the help question mark for the "Lightweight checkout" option:

> Also build parameters will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode.

Found that in latest comments of [JENKINS-28447](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28447)

Comment: this should really be the accepted answer; it's a simple concise fix that solves the problem and doesn't involve any custom scripting

Comment: Confirmed you can use parameter values if you uncheck Lightweight checkout, thanks.

Comment: @raner In fairness, all "[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)" means is that it worked for the question asker, not that it's the "best" answer in general…

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, go further by creating a multibranch workflow project, so that each branch is built automatically with its own history.

Comment: The multi branch workflow project is an interesting idea, I will have to test this out. As we have 100+ devs with several feature branches each sometimes, I have to find a way to organize these branches in clear way.

Comment: This should be a comment or just added to your [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438433/542251)

Comment: For large repos this is a bad idea. Multibranch pipeline can quickly exhaust your GH api rate limit.

Comment: @apanzerj reasonably recent versions of `github-branch-source` take care to slow down if necessary before exhausting the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workflow DSL script described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/jSKwSKbaXq8/dG2mn6iyDQAJ

In that script, I have a build parameter called FREEBSD_SRC_URL , which is
passed down to the workflow.  Based on different parameters in that URL,
a different branch can be checked out.

If you are using git, you can still use the same technique for passing a build parameter down to the script, but you would need to do things slightly differently.  For example, you could define a parameter BRANCH_NAME in your job and do something like this in your workflow script:

```
String checkout_url = "https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins"
String branch_name = "master"

if (getBinding().hasVariable("CHECKOUT_URL")) {
    // override default URL from build parameter
    checkout_url = CHECKOUT_URL
}
if (getBinding().hasVariable("BRANCH_NAME")) {
    // override default branch from build parameter
    branch_name = BRANCH_NAME
}

node {
    // Do the git checkout
    git branch: "${branch_name}", url: "${checkout_url}"
}
```